# Container won't stretch to bottom (tried the usual solutions)

Tags: html, css

I can't get my divs stretch to the bottom of my page. I have html,body height: 100%, min-height: 100% on my divs, but my container won't stretch to the bottom. My content goes to the bottom of the page fine, but my div won't stretch to the bottom. I have tried the overflow property and that didn't work either.

EDIT: Here's some of my CSS:

```
div.container {
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1280px;
}

div.content {
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1024px;
}

div.center {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1024px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: a code or snippets might be usefull..

Comment: If your content is floated or position:absolute, this is the expected behavior. But hard to say without samples.

Comment: it would definitely help to see your code. use the code snippet button in the editor maybe... If not here maybe use jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of setup you have? - http://jsfiddle.net/jordanlewis/rqvwr/